# Behavior of WS_CLIPCHILDREN and InvalidateRect in Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi

To reduce flickering I create my parent windows using the WS_CLIPCHILDREN flag and I call InvalidateRect during the WM_SIZE event. This approach has worked well in Windows XP. However, I recently started programming on Windows 7 and I'm now experiencing rendering issues when resizing windows. When resizing a window its contents is not refreshed until I do something that forces a redraw, like minimizing and restoring the window.

I've tried following up the InvalidateRect with a UpdateWindow call but with no effect.

Does anyone know how to do it correctly?

**Update**
I found a workaround: calling `InvalidateRect(childHWND, NULL, FALSE)`
on all child windows followed by a `InvalidateRect(parentHWND, NULL, TRUE)` on the parent window fixes the rendering problem without introducing noticeable flickering.

Other suggestions are still welcome!

**Update 2**
I tried the `RedrawWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ALLCHILDREN)` but that resulted in some rendering issues (left-over pixels).

**Update 3**
The RedrawWindow works when followed by a `InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE)`. Thanks @interjay!

Comment: I wish someone at Microsoft would publish a clear, concise, how-to resize w/o flicker that is compatible with all versions of its OSes!

Comment: I've edited my answer with a fix. If you reply to me again, please add a comment under my answer or I probably won't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try calling [`RedrawWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911%28VS.85%29.aspx), passing flags `RDW_INVALIDATE` and `RDW_ALLCHILDREN`.

**Edit**:

To redraw the background, you can add RDW_ERASE. If you want to redraw the background on the parent but not the children, call both `RedrawWindow` and `InvalidateRect(...,TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem.
I looked at this solution but finally I came up with the following:

```
void WindowClass::Invalidate(BOOL bErase)
{
    base::Invalidate(bErase);

    // traverse along all the child windows.
    for (CWnd* pChild = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); pChild != NULL; pChild = pChild->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
    {
        // Let them do the invalidate also.
        pChild->Invalidate(bErase);
    }
}
```

I do hope this helps. . .

Answer (score 0):

I found this snippet somewhere recently when browsing for something else - and it indicated that by removing **CS_VREDRAW** and **CS_HREDRAW** from the **WNDCLASS** for your window, that it would reduce the artifacts created when resizing a window.

I use the following snippet to achieve this, though I cannot say how much real impact I have actually noticed it having:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT & cs)
{
    // do standard thing
    if (!CMFCToolboxMDIFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs))
        return FALSE;

    // ensure a thinner border
    cs.dwExStyle &= ~WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;

    // avoid repainting when resized by changing the class style
    WNDCLASS wc;
    VERIFY(GetClassInfo(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), cs.lpszClass, &wc));
    cs.lpszClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(0, wc.hCursor, wc.hbrBackground, wc.hIcon);

    return TRUE;
}
```